# Capturing web requests from page

Tags: c#

Is it possible for me to capture all outgoing requests from a specific webpage, modify them and then send them on their way again.

I'm thinking along the lines of a HTTP Handler or Module but I'm not sure if this would work or where to start.

I only want to capture from a specific page.

Cheers

P.S Feel free to add better tags if needs be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Create-Http-Module.aspx) is a quite nice example how to create your own Http Module that captures connections and then make a requests log. It should be helpful to start.